# Divide huge DataTable equally to multiple 

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

I've a Datatable with about 156K and I want to make 6 Datatable and divide the records to each of them like table1 will hold rows from 0 to 30k and table 2 will hold rows from 30k1 to 60k and so on.

the big table is ordered with numerical column that goes from 0 to 14

any suggestions on how to do this without looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ's [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx):

Testdata:

```
Dim tbl1 = New DataTable
tbl1.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Int32))
tbl1.Columns.Add("Text", GetType(String))
For rowIndex As Int32 = 1 To 156000
    tbl1.Rows.Add(rowIndex, "Row " & rowIndex)
Next
```

Split into multiple tables:

```
Dim tableCount = 6 
Dim divisor = tbl1.Rows.Count / tableCount ' needed to identify each group '
Dim tables() As DataTable = tbl1.AsEnumerable().
        Select(Function(r, i) New With {.Row = r, .Index = i}).
        GroupBy(Function(x) Math.Floor(x.Index / divisor)).
        Select(Function(g) g.Select(Function(x) x.Row).CopyToDataTable()).
        ToArray()
```

Note that this will split them into tables with 26000 rows in each since 156000 / 6 = 26000.

Comment: but can this manage it when the rows cannot be divided by 6 like 156003 rows?

Comment: Tried it and its really perfect,Thanks again

Comment: @user1570048: I'm glad i could help. Note that Linq also uses loops although it doesn't look much.

Comment: i know, but i mean without me using the loops :D

Answer (score 0):

Do it on database level?

Select from your table into others then delete original table.

Comment: problem is i don't know how can i select from row 0 to 30k and from row60k to 90k , TOP BUTTOM will not do the job i want to divide it to 6 datatables